# Why is jquery-3.5.1.min.js being returned from a request.params.id expression

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, ejs

Im using Express js along with type script for a simple app for a school project.
This router gets is the edit page for a contact list we have to make. It shows the ID of the current contact that is being edited in the searchbar. The issue is when I want to get the ID from the req (request) it outputs 2 values. One of them is the ID i want but the other is some jquery js file version and I have 0 idea how to fix this.

```
router.get("/edit/:id", async(req, res) => {
let id = req.params.id;

let editContact = await Contact.findById(id, {}, {}, (err, itemForEdit) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Profile That will be edited:", itemForEdit)
        res.render('../Views/Content/editContact.ejs', { title: 'Home Page', Login: LoginValue, username: currentUser, Contacts: ContactList });
    }
}); 
})
```

When the console.log shows it shows the object Im trying to grab and then also this message.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "jquery-3.5.1.min.js" (type string) at path "_id" for model "contactSchema"
```

When I do `console.log(req.params)` it shows 2 param objects:

```
{ id: 'jquery-3.5.1.min.js' } (NOT THE ONE IM LOOKING FOR)

{ id: '60ca19ec4984810cec017b05' } (THIS IS THE ONE I WANT)
```

I dont have this called any ware else that I can think of and have checked many times.

Please HELP!

Comment: You might be having a webpage that uses relative path to `jquery.min.js` in a `<script>` element. Either use a different path for the script (like `wwwroot/js/jquery.min.js`) or validate `id`. You can use middlewares like `sirv` to serve script assets for specific HTTP endpoints.

Comment: @Klaider Should I just remove all the jquery.min.js script files I see in my project. Does this mean the problem is coming from the file / page where the a tag button is to bring you to the edit page.

Comment: I've answered to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a webpage where a script element (`<script>` tag) refers to a JQuery bundle. You can validate `id` to check if it is a valid user ID (like `/[a-z][a-z_0-9]+/i.test("id")`); then, if it is valid, resolve to user, otherwise resolve to a file using Node.js file-system module.

It'd be easier to serve the scripts at a specific HTTP endpoint (different from `/edit/xxx.js`). You can use
the [`sirv`](http://npmjs.com/package/sirv) middleware for this, for example:

```js
import Sirv from 'sirv';

router.use('/js', Sirv('./res/js', {
    dev: true,
}))
```

Then make sure the `<script>` tags refer to, for example, `/js/jquery.js` (note the start slash).

Comment: Thank you for the amazing help and I have figured out the issue. It was because the Jquery Bundle I was trying to access's file path was incorrect.

Comment: God Bless You :)

Comment: @AlexGreen Glad to help! :-)